# How do I like a user model with this setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have setup a polymorphic liking in my my app where a user can like other models e.g book, chapter, article... Now I tried to take it a little further by allowing a user like another user but I'm running to this error:

```
Validation failed: User must exist
```

pointing to

```
likes.where(item: item).create!
```

This is my initial setup for liking other models excluding the user model

like.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :item, polymorphic: true
```

user.rb

```
has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy

def toggle_like!(item)
    if like = likes.where(item: item).first
      like.destroy
    else
      likes.where(item: item).create!
    end
end

def likes?(item)
    likes.where(item: item).exists?
end
```

likes_controller.rb

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def toggle
        if params[:book_id]
            item = Book.friendly.find(params[:book_id])
        elsif params[:user_id]
            item = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
        end

        current_user.toggle_like!(item)
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    end
end
```

book.rb

```
has_many :likes, as: :item, dependent: :destroy
```

For a user to like another user, i adjusted the user.rb from

```
has_many :likes
```

to

```
has_many :likes, as: :item, dependent: :destroy
```

This is when I get the error

```
Validation failed: User must exist
```

pointing to

```
likes.where(item: item).create!
```

in the user.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep `has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy` and also add `has_many :received_likes, as: :item, class_name: "Like", dependent: :destroy`. I think that will fix it. Because when you put `User has_many: :likes, as: :item`, and removed `User has_many: :likes`, this means that the association `Like belongs_to :user` was one-sided.

Comment: I modified my files as you said. Can you please show a way to display on the users profile page? I tried ```<%= link_to 'like', toggle_like_path(user_id: @user.id), class: "btn btn-sm btn-light #{'is-liked' if current_user.likes?(@user)}", method: 'post' %>``` I got Item must exist error this time, thanks!

Comment: You are passing user_id but in your toggle method you have params[:username]. I guess that s the issue. You should change that to accept polymorphic associations. What if you have 12 different models as items in the future? Putting 12 ifs is not very dry. Try passing item_type and item_id and then in the toggle method do `item = params[:item_type].constantize.find(params[:item_id])`.
 And then in link_to path pass `item_type: @user.class.to_s` and `item_id: @user.id`. You might want to whitelist specific values for item_type

Comment: I also added optional: true to the like class

Comment: That will make the error disappear but it can also cause creation of likes that are not owned by any user. Might or might not be what you want. Depends on your application.